# Click fora das ações de um Notification

Tags: android, android-notification

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira dentro de um Ongoing Notification para que ao clickar fora dos botões mas ainda na notificação ela execute uma ação pré determinada?

Answer (score -1):

Após declarar um XML do layaout dar um ID para ele, e usar ele com o proposito de ação ou uma intent, assim quando for clickado ele vai poder abrir uma UI ou executar algum comando